# Reload routes not working on Vue JS

Tags: http, vuejs2, vue-router

I just finished to build my portfolio on Vue js 2 and went live.
I have three views. When I reload the home view it's ok but on the two other ones I have several error messages.

```
Error parsing a meta element's content: ';' is not a valid key-value pair separator. Please use ',' instead.
Work:30 A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script,
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://website.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

It's the first time for me to go live with a single page webapp architecture.
Any idea to fix this please?

Here is the router file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/views/Home'
import Work from '@/views/Work'
import About from '@/views/About'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export default new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/Work', component: Work },
    { path: '/About', component: About }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Some code would be useful :)

Comment: Sure @webnoob but which one as I don't know from where comes the issue... I will post my router code and please do not hesitate if you want to see something else. :) Also In Dev mode everything is fine but the problem occure in production.

Comment: Have you followed the steps in the [Example Configurations](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html) ?

Comment: You right! It seems to be the solution. Thank you for your time and attention :) Merry Christmas!!!

Comment: No problem, I've added an answer so others know how to fix. Feel free to tick it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [example configurations](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html) on the Vue Router website. They often fix issues that happen server side when all is in dev.

Comment: @BeeLee vue-cli only sets up the clientside code; server config still has to be done separately.

Answer (score 2):

**In some special cases, [this trick](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html) will not work, like when your project is in the subfolder on your domain.**

For that, you have to add these lines. Replace your **subfolder name** with

> {Your sub folder name}

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /{Your sub folder name}/index.html [L]
```

Only apply to apache. Message me if you need any help for deploying you app on **apache**.

Comment: Very nice! That helped me.